# scala method named 'type'

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In **scala environment**, I use **java class** containing method `type()` which seems to cause troubles as `type` is a scala keyword.

I need to call the real `type` method (defined in java class), not the scala one.

```
val c = new JavaClass(...)
val s = new ScalaClass(c.type(), c.name())
// identifier expected but 'type' found.
```

Can I somehow call the `type` method defined in java class?

Note: I can't rewrite the java class since it's a provided library without edit permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can call the java method by surrounding it with backtics

```
c.`type`()
```